# Preventing direct browser access to a Wordpress plugin's text files

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin, "custom-plugin", that has some .txt files that help configure it. I want to prevent direct browser access to those .txt files.

I've never used htaccess before, but what I'm trying is to edit the root .htaccess file and add these lines:

```
# BEGIN custom-plugin
# Block web browser access to .txt files.
RedirectMatch .*/custom-plugin/.*\.txt$ http://MyWebsite.com
# END custom-plugin
```

Alas, it's not working, I can still directly access *`https://www.MyWebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/plugin_settings.txt`*

Am I doing the htaccess wrong?

All I want to do is prevent access to those files - is RedirectMatch the wrong choice?

NOTE: This is the root htaccess file (located at *`public_html/.htaccess`*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why your redirect is not working (assuming you already have other directives in your `.htaccess` file that are working). Maybe you have a conflict with other directives.

However, if you want to block access to these `.txt` files then you don't want to redirect the request, so `RedirectMatch` is not the correct tool for the job.

Simply block access to all `.txt` files:

```
<Files "*.txt">
Require all denied
</Files>
```

This would return a 403 Forbidden for *all* HTTP requests for `.txt` files. Assuming you don't need to be specific to your "custom-plugin". Also assumes Apache 2.4+

*Aside:* Are these `.txt`/config files really required for the plugins continued use, not just for installation?!

> **UPDATE:** I just want to block ones in my own plugin's folder

If you don't want to create an additional `.htaccess` file in  the plugins directory (would have the added bonus that it can simply be distributed with the plugin) then you can use a mod_rewrite directive in the root `.htaccess` file.

The following would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing WordPress mod_rewrite directives:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/.+\.txt$ - [F]
```

Or, if you want to be a little more flexible as to the directory structure:

```
RewriteRule /custom-plugin/.+\.txt$ - [F]
```

The above also returns a 403 Forbidden for any request that matches the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The `L` flag is not required when the `F` flag is used. The *substitution string* consists of a single hyphen (`-`), indicating *no substitution*.

Alternatively, on Apache 2.4+, you can use an Apache Expression:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/custom-plugin/.+\.txt$#">
Require all denied
</If>
```

Comment: It's a custom plugin - I configure it via the .txt files; I haven't written a Wordpress settings page for it. I also don't want to block *every* .txt file in the entire Wordpress install (I don't know what that might mess up as far as other plugins go - presumably mine are the only .txt files in existence, but still...), I just want to block ones in my own plugin's folder, if that makes sense.

Comment: I've updated my answer to target the specific "custom-plugin" directory. Also consider using an extension other than `.txt` for config files, such as `.cfg` or `.conf` (easily blocked en masse) or even using dot-files (which are blocked by default on Apache / Linux). `.txt` files are, by default, served with a text/plain mime-type and are prone to line-ending conversion when transferred over (S)FTP in ASCII mode (which may or may not be desirable depending on how the files are read).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Both your other solutions worked fine for me, once I put them at the *TOP* of the .htaccess file, as you specified. As a programmer, whose's new to webdev, I assumed lower down overruled higher up. =P

Comment: I also took your advice and used an alternate extension. And I changed the RewriteRule to **- [L,R=404]** so it returns a 404, rather than "*Yea, this file exists but you can't access it*" 403.

Comment: (oh, it's still serving .txt files - must be how the webserver is set up. But no matter, using your advice of renaming them .conf worked fine for me - I greatly appreciate your help)

Comment: "I assumed lower down overruled higher up" - although, as with any programming environment, earlier statements can prevent later statements from running (exit early). `[L,R=404]` - minor point, but the `L` flag is not strictly required when using a non-3xx code with the `R` flag (it is implied). "it's still serving .txt files - must be how the webserver is set up" - if you are still trying to block `.txt` files in `.htaccess` then it's most probably an error with your directives. (The webserver will by default serve `.txt` files as plain text, but this can always be overridden.)